# Session variable not taking effect in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session-variables, background-color

I have a session variable in my asp.net application. The session variable holds a value from the database, that reflects a customized HTML color value.
In my application, I have an asp button with server side code

`btnContinue.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(Session("ContinueColor"))`

**Issue:** However, when I run the application, the color value is not being reflected in the button.

I did double check, and the session variable does hold the correct value.
There are other objects, that use session variables to display colors, and they are working fine.

How can I resolve this issue?

**Update**: When I force a color "btnContinue.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Blue", that works perfectly fine.

Comment: this could mean your button background color is being changed after this line again or its styles are being cleared.

Comment: have you checked the rendered HTML to see if any CSS class is messing with button's background color?

Comment: Make sure there are no app_theme skins overriding things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a hex code, you might want to use ColorTranslator instead:

```
btnContinue.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Session("ContinueColor").ToString());
```

Looking at the color information you posted in your comment, I think you just need to cast the session object as type Color:

```
btnContinue.BackColor = DirectCast(Session("ContinueColor"), System.Drawing.Color)
```

**EDIT**

I found the solution:

```
btnContinue.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("{Name=48E8DD, ARGB=(0, 0, 0, 0)}")
```

In your case, it would be:

```
btnContinue.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(Session("ContinueColor").ToString())
```

Comment: What is the value that's stored in session?

Comment: sorry... I wrote the wrong values.... the btnContinue session value is: "{Name=48E8DD, ARGB=(0, 0, 0, 0)}"

Comment: That's an empty color, hence the empty color that is applied to the button.

Comment: See updated answer. I think you just need to cast it as a color.

Comment: @James... I can say that button is holding the correct session value because I do a "btnContinue.Text = Session("ContinueColor") and it displays the correct value when the page is rendered

Comment: I think you should convert the color to HTML using `ColorTranslator.ToHtml` before storing it in session, so you can use `ColorTranslator.FromHtml` when trying to set the color again.

Comment: when I use the ColorTranslator.FromHTML I get an error message = "48E8DD is not a valid value for Int32."

Comment: When you're saving the color to `Session("ContinueColor")`, can you save it as HTML color: `Session("ContinueColor") = ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.Red)`

Comment: I found the solution. See edited answer. Tested it myself, and it resolves to a color.

Comment: After implementing your "btnContinue.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(Session("ContinueColor").ToString())" ->>> Error: Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.Drawing.Color'.

Comment: I think you're doing something wrong. The `FromName` function expects a string, so you shouldn't be getting that error

Answer (score 0):

Which part of the page life cycle are you setting the color?  Maybe the session data has not been read yet?  Session should be ready after PageLoad.

I recommend setting a break point immediately after this line of code to make sure nothing else is overriding it - theme.

```
btnContinue.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(Session("ContinueColor"))
```

Comment: Page_Load event. All other objects are being set at the page_load event as well.

Comment: I set a breakpoint and I did "AddWatch" The value of BackColor stays the correct color value throughout the step through process. However, when the page is displayed, the btnContinue has a blank back color

Comment: Is it possible that you're resetting the button color somewhere after Page_Load?

Comment: I do a global search for the btnContinue, and the page load is the only place where it's backcolor is set